# How to optimize logical app bad performance

Tags: performance, azure, azure-logic-apps

I  have built a large logic app on the Azure portal (about 485 actions) but when I open logic app designer the scrolling is too slow and if I want to create any action it Takes time and it have a bad performance. Any advice?

Comment: raise ticket to MS support you will get better recommendation.

Comment: The advice I can give is break your logic app into smaller chunks, follow the Single responsibility  principle and keep it simple

Comment: Hi, may I know if the answer I provided can help you optimize your logic app ? If it helps, could you please mark it as "accepted", thanks in advance~

Answer (score 1):

You should consider separating the 485 actions into multiple (in your case, many) logic apps with single responsibilities. You can then chain them together using appropriate triggers.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate your logic app to several parts and implement different functions in them. For example, if we want to combine a user's name and email, we can do it in "childLogic" first (the screenshot below is my child logic app):

[image]

Then add it(childLogic) to your parent logic app by [create nested logic apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-http-endpoint#create-nested-logic-apps).
[image]